# monit - "else if succeeded then exec"

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

I have a problem with monit executing script *on success.*

`~/.monitrc`:

```
check host example.com with address example.com
if failed url http://example.com/startpage and content == "mainBaner"
timeout 10 seconds
then exec "/usr/local/bin/monit_example_error.sh"
    else if succeeded then exec "/usr/local/bin/monit_example_ok.sh"
```

It appears to run the script if there's an error, but not when there's no error.

Log shows that the tests are ran and succeed, `/var/log/monit.log`:

```
[CEST Jun  8 12:24:52] debug    : 'example.com' succeeded testing protocol [HTTP] at INET[example.com:80/startpage] via TCP
[CEST Jun  8 12:25:22] debug    : 'example.com' succeeded connecting to INET[example.com:80/dlibra] via TCP
[CEST Jun  8 12:25:46] debug    : HTTP: Regular expression matches
[CEST Jun  8 12:25:46] debug    : 'example.com' succeeded testing protocol [HTTP] at INET[example.com:80/startpage] via TCP
[CEST Jun  8 12:26:16] debug    : 'example.com' succeeded connecting to INET[example.com:80/dlibra] via TCP
[CEST Jun  8 12:26:39] debug    : HTTP: Regular expression matches
```

I have checked that running `/usr/local/bin/monit_example_ok.sh` works as expected (creating relevant status file in relevant dir).

OS:

```
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

% uname -a
Linux ql 3.13.0-119-generic #166-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 3 12:18:55 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Monit:

```
ii  monit                                1:5.6-2                                    amd64        utility for monitoring and managing daemons or similar progra
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Succeed* action is only executed after a *fail* event is solved (i.e. when going from state **fail** to state **success**), not when things behave as expected.